# Orchard overriding customform textarea template

Tags: templates, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

**How to override/create customform textarea template?**

Using Orchard 1.8. In order to style a custom form I wish to addclass to the **fieldset tag wrapping the textarea.** Using the shapetracer it is not clear to me

(I can override other  tags for example the 'boolean field types. 
(E.g copy Modules/Orchard.Fields/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/Boolean.Edit.cshtml to Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/Boolean.Edit.cshtml) but unsure for textarea. (copying **Input.Edit.cshtml doesnt work** it appears.)

Answer (score 2):

You can override the TextArea by copying the file **~/Core/Common/Views/Body.Editor.cshtml** to a location of higher priority (like **~/Themes/*MyTheme*/Views/Body.Editor.cshtml**) and editing it there.  However, that cshtml file handles more than just TextArea type - it would override the rendering of all body editors.  To be specific to just textarea, you should create a file named **Body.Editor-TextArea.cshtml**

Answer (score 0):

Usually, i just override the whole HTML. You know the names/ids right? so you can easily copy the HTML from the ShapeTracer and copy in your new Alternate. 
While the name/ids stay the same, everything will wire up properly. 
 
Check your "EditorTemplate", but before creating and alternate, copy the HTML instead of the Template.